# Fast Automatic Differentiation for numpy?

Tags: numpy, automatic-differentiation

I would like to use automatic differentiation to calculate gradients to function written in numpy.

I've come across a number of packages, including

- [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd)
- [tangent](https://github.com/google/tangent)
- [chainer](https://github.com/chainer/chainer)

But none of them seem to support things like numba and numexpr, which I'd normally use to accelerate my python code.

What packages do people use for this?

p.s. I know there's also stuff like tensorflow and pytorch, but I would like to keep my code in numpy

Comment: It would be useful to know the function and why you need to differentiate it automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Jax has the features you're looking for. See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/quickstart.html

Comment: To the downvoter, why the downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but generally answers with just a link are discouraged. You should give some description of what is in the link, even if its just a quotation. This makes the answer here more useful and avoids a situation where a link eventually dies, leaving no information in the answer.